# Remove empty cells from table but keep table structure in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with some empty cells as shown below.

| Primary | Proficiency | Secondary | Proficiency | Sub | Proficiency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | Windows | Intermediate |  |  |
| Web | Expert | Web | Expert | MVC | Expert |
|  |  |  |  | C# | Expert |
| Finance | Expert | Accounts | Expert | Math | Expert |

What I am trying to achieve is, in a button click, I want to rearrange the empty cells to last of each columns so that cells with data comes on top. And keep the table structure intact.
Expected table is shown below.

| Primary | Proficiency | Secondary | Proficiency | Sub | Proficiency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Web | Expert | Windows | Intermediate | MVC | Expert |
| Finance | Expert | Web | Expert | C# | Expert |
|  |  | Accounts | Expert | Math | Expert |

**What i have done so far**

---

I'm blank. I tried to hide the cells using the below code. But it is not rearranging the cells and the table structure breaks.

```
$('.subTable td:empty').hide();
```

Is there any way to achieve this. I can loop through each td but how to shift the tds to top?
What is the efficient way to achieve this. Please share your comments.

Comment: Hi, so that value should go upwards ? if above `tds` are empty ?

Comment: @Swati Yes. the values should go upwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this.

```js
const tbody = document.getElementById("tbl").getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
// data contains all the cells and then pack them by columns
const data = [];

[...tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")].forEach(tr => {
  data.push([...tr.getElementsByTagName("td")].map(td => td.innerText));
});

const cols = data[0].length;
for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
  const values = []
  for (let row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    if (data[row][col] !== "") {
      values.push(data[row][col]);
      data[row][col] = "";
    }
  }
  values.forEach((v, row) => {
    data[row][col] = v;
  });
}

// reconstruct the innerHTML of tbody
tbody.innerHTML = data.filter(row => row.some(cell => cell !== "")).map(row => {
  return "<tr>" + row.map(cell => `<td>${cell}</td>`).join("") + "</tr>";
}).join("");
```

```css
.s-table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.s-table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl" class="s-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Primary</th>
      <th>Proficiency</th>
      <th>Secondary</th>
      <th>Proficiency</th>
      <th>Sub</th>
      <th>Proficiency</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Windows</td>
      <td>Intermediate</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Web</td>
      <td>Expert</td>
      <td>Web</td>
      <td>Expert</td>
      <td>MVC</td>
      <td>Expert</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>C#</td>
      <td>Expert</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Finance</td>
      <td>Expert</td>
      <td>Accounts</td>
      <td>Expert</td>
      <td>Math</td>
      <td>Expert</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```